# How to find the correct element for a checkbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Python and Selenium, and have got a little stuck with trying to click a check box. I have given my code so far down below.

My eventual aim is to populate a list of payees on HSBC from my spreadsheet, and once that's done I can manually click on submit, in order to pay them all. It works fine up until the point where it selects the payee.

At the moment, when I try to select the checkbox I'm getting an error "no such element. Unable to locate element." etc. I've copied the list of elements I copied from HSBC. Does anyone have any idea of what I can try?

I've replace sensitive info with asterisks. I had to insert the HTML elements as code, but I hope it's come out OK otherwise.

```
<td class="Box-sc-qbwqq9-0 TableBodyCell__DefaultBodyCell-sc-cl0sox-0 gijpJg eYTdev sc-hLBbgP cHXHLo">
  <label class="css-1kjmcnq">
    <input class="CheckboxInput-design-system__x7khws-0 hdyOlF" data-testid="Checkbox" data-id="Checkbox" type="checkbox" aria-label="Payee TOBY **** with reference number ******* ******* having sort code 00-00-00 and account number 00000000" aria-checked="false">
    <div data-id="CheckboxBox" class="CheckboxBox-design-system__sc-1ijfz2q-0 ckrTKH small css-4cffwv" mode="light">
      <div display="inline-flex" class="Box-qbwqq9-0 Icon__IconWrapper-y4p3lz-0 blYcNt eYXvhY Icon CheckboxIcon-design-system__sc-1i4adeu-0 fgbehG small" data-testid="Icon-StatusYesThick" data-trackid="Icon-StatusYesThick@1.6.0" data-id="CheckboxIcon">
        <svg class="Box-sc-y5ctq9-0 SvgIcon__SvgIconBox-sc-1vnlbss-0 htGorq boQDDw SvgIcon" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 18 18" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" data-testid="StatusYesThickIcon" data-id="Icon" fill="currentColor">
          <path fill="none" d="M0 0h18v18H0z" opacity=".25"></path>
          <path d="M5.916 15.942l-5.81-5.808L1.378 8.86l4.538 4.537L16.622 2.693l1.272 1.274z"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</td>
```

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

web = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(web)

wb = load_workbook('D:\\Documents\\*******\\HSBCPythonPaymentFile.xlsx', data_only=True, 
read_only=False)
web.get("https://online-banking.business.hsbc.co.uk/portalserver/hsbc/login")
ws = wb.active
x = 52

wb.save('D:\\Documents\\*********\\Musician Payments\\HSBCPythonPaymentFile.xlsx')

while ws.cell(x,1).value !=None:
    musician = ws.cell(x,1).value + " " + ws.cell(x,2).value
    input("Press Enter to continue...")

    musiciansearch = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input')
    musiciansearch.send_keys(musician)

    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()

    element = web.find_element_by_id('Checkbox')
    action = ActionChains(web)
    action.click(on_element= element)

    x = x + 1
```

Comment: I fixed the HTML formatting in the question

Answer (score 1):

The INPUT you are trying to click is

```
<input class="CheckboxInput-design-system__x7khws-0 hdyOlF" data-testid="Checkbox" data-id="Checkbox" type="checkbox" aria-label="..." aria-checked="false">
```

I shortened the `aria-label` attribute because we're going to ignore that for now because we have other attributes we can use to simply identify this element. The first thing I look for is an ID or name. This has neither. We could try one of the classes but they look like they might be obfuscated and may change on page reload... only you could determine that but we still have other, better choices. I would go immediately for either `data-testid="Checkbox"` or `data-id="Checkbox"`. Those might be unique on the page. I would try the two CSS selectors below and see if one returns the INPUT you are looking for.

```
input[data-testid='Checkbox']
input[data-id='Checkbox']
```